# Using keyup function without changing editing text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript function keyup with editable div and text input filed use for add text into editable div so my code work fine but recently i am add CKeditor plugin for editing text.

for example if i set text in input field keyup function work and these text set into editable div now i want to use Ckeditor for customizing after customization if i want to change text with input field than editing lost and return on default style.

**Javasacript**

```
$('#input1').keyup(function () {
    txt = $('#input1').val();
    $('#field1').text(txt);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input1">

<div id="field1" contentEditable='true'; ></div>
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with not calling `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` on the event, but I am not sure I fully understand your question to be able to attempt an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#input1", function() {
    txt = $('#input1').val();
    $('#field1').text(txt);
});
```

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/HTS65/)

#### EDIT 1:

If you want to make sure that the initial `input` is also updated upon change of `div`, you should try the following:

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", "#field1", function() {
   $('#input1').val($('#field1').text()); 
});
```

Try clicking on the button or modifying `div's` content via Firebug, for example and see how `input` is also changed.

I wouldn't use `keyup` in your case but changed it as such upon your request.

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/qAYE3/)

Comment: your example work fine but First i need keyup function and also need reverse work.i mean when if i write in editable div this time these text set in input1.